# Unable insert more than 1 entry in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my schema. user_id and other_id are supposed to be unique (composite).

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FriendshipSchema = new Schema({

  user_id: {
    type: String,
    default: "",  
    trim: true,
unique:true,
  },
  other_id: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
unique:true,
  },

  status: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    default: "none",
  },

});
FriendshipSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Friendship', FriendshipSchema)
```

and here is my server-side code. pretty straightforward insert using Mongoose.

```
app.post('/api/user/friendrequest', function(req, res){
var friendship = new Friendship(req.body);
console.log(req.body);

 Friendship.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length){
console.log('abac');
        }else{
            friendship.save(function(err){

            if (err)
            {
             console.log(err)
            }
            });
        }
    });
    });
```

I get this response in console but no more than 1 entry is saved in MongoDB. I've deleted indexes as well and its still not working. btw 'user_id' is unique in another Collection. I also don't get any error when i log console.log(err).

```
{ user_id: 'google-oauth2|117175967810648931400',
  status: 'pending',
  other_id: 'facebook|10209430751350509' }
abac
```

Here are the indexes for the friendships collection.

```
 db.friendships.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "kola.friendships"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the "combination" of fields to be "unique" here rather than be treated individually as such.

That means your schema should instead be defined like this:

```
var FriendshipSchema = new Schema({

  user_id: {
    type: String,
    default: "",  
    trim: true,
  },
  other_id: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },

  status: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    default: "none",
  },

});

// Instead define the schema level index here
FriendshipShema.index({ "user_id": 1, "other_id": 1 },{ "unique": true });

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Friendship', FriendshipSchema);
```

The best part of this is that you don't need any plugin to support what you want to do.

Please do make sure you run a [`.dropIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndexes/) on the collection to get rid of any individual "unique" indexes that will interfere with the correct operation.

Also see [`.createindex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) and ["Unique Indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) in the core documentation for more information.

Comment: I dropped the table, removed all indexes apart from _id_ but still I'm only able to add 1 entry and still no errors. however at one stage, I got this 'driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: kola.friendships index: user_id_1_other_id_1 dup key: { : "google-oauth2|117175967810648931400", : "google-oauth2|109598513284156650220" }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }'

Comment: @AlamgirQazi Well yes, that is by design. You can only ever have **one** combination of the fields. What are you expecting?

Comment: I have 5 Users A, B, C, D, E each with different user_ids. for one record, I want AB, for one i want AC etc. since everyone has unique keys, I should be able to add them right?

Comment: @AlamgirQazi That's what I'm enforcing here you can have combination of AB AC AE etc, but never another one such as BA since that relationship is already defined with a unique entry. ie AB == BA. Please note the the "correction" on your code is that it was not possible for you to define even A more than once. Making the unique constraint the :"combination" fixes this.

Comment: Thank you! yes. that's exactly what I want and now I understand that indexes were needed but I'm still only able to add one record. means only one A exists at a time. No idea what I'm doing wrong. Maybe its because user_id is unique in another collection?

Comment: @AlamgirQazi Different collections cannot effect another. You did remove the plugin you were using from the schema definition didn't you? And also you removed the `unique` constraints from the individual schema fields? That is what I was showing you here, so you do need to follow the example "exactly".

Comment: aah.. Fixed it. the problem was in server.js

 `Friendship.find({}, function (err, docs) {
//         if (docs.length){
// console.log('friendship exists');
//         }else{
            friendship.save(function(err){

            if (err)
            {
             console.log(err)
            }
            });`

no idea what (docs.length) checked.

Thank you for helping me out.